# javascript async call in a for loop

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Rookie question. It could be a possible duplicate, but I can't wrap my head around how to restructure the code. How should I structure the below code so that the console would print the following:

Here1
Here2
Here1
Here2
Here1
Here2

Now it goes:

Here1
Here1
Here1
Here2
Here2
Here2

Thanks for your help.

```
var record;

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    sendRequest(selectTestsToRun('something1'), 'someTest1');
}

this.someTest1 = function(resObj, testToRun){
    console.log('Here1');
    record = resObj.value;
    sendRequest(selectTestsToRun('something2'), 'someTest2');
};

this.someTest2  = function(resObj, testToRun){
    console.log('Here2');
};

function selectTestsToRun(toDo){
    var data;

    switch( toDo) {
        case 'something1':
            data = 'postMessage';
            break;

        case 'something2':
            data = 'postMessage'+record;
            break;
    }

    return data;
}

function sendRequest(data , toDo ){

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  url,
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        onload: function(response) {
            var resObj = JSON.parse(response);
            this[toDo](resObj,toDo);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: console.log will print on each new line everytime it is called

Comment: @Dummy: That's not the point, it's the sequence that's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `for` loop at all. Instead, you want `someTest2` to kick off the next iteration of the "loop":

```
var i = 0;
next();

function next() {
    if (i < 3) {
        sendRequest(selectTestsToRun('something1'), 'someTest1');
        ++i;
    }
}

this.someTest2  = function(resObj, testToRun){
    console.log('Here2');
    next();                                          // <==== Note
};
```

In the above, I've baked that into `someTest2`, but you can of course pass a callback around to decouple the loop from `someTest2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that AJAX calls happen asynchronously while the loop executes synchronously.

The loop calls test1 back to back, while the AJAX request take atleast 300ms  to make a trip to and from the server. This most certainly will happen long after the loop has finished.

You need to use a callback (or promise) to call the next function.  You can place the logic that determines which one to call next in the call back.  Here is an example using jQuery for the Ajax communication.

I went old school and used a counter that is only incremented by the first calling function. When the counter reaches your limit, it acts like a switch and stops the viscous cycle.

You can see it work here:https://[jsbin.com/wohife/](https://jsbin.com/wohife/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 0;


    function test1() {
        if (counter < 3) {
            sendRequest(1);
            console.log('here 1');
        }

        counter++;
    }

    function test2() {
        sendRequest(2);
        console.log('here 2');
    }

    function sendRequest(requesterId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsbin.com/sohefe/1.json',
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .success(function(data, status, req) {

            if (requesterId === 1) {
                test2();
            }
            else {
                test1();
            }

        });
    }

    test1();
});
```